# How do I handle options in a packaged Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to deploy an existing JS app as a Packaged Crome App to make it distributable in the Chrome Web Store.

In "legacy packaged apps", there is/used to be a way to specify an `options_ui` page (in old legacy (legacy-legacy?) apps it was `options_page`) which would be accessible via a special link from your app, or by automatic link from from within `chrome://extensions`.

There doesn't seem to be any mention about how to migrate the `options_*` feature, but if the `manifest.json` of a Chrome App has the `options_ui` key it generates the following warning on the extensions page:

- *'options_ui' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.*

---

*(References)*

- [Chrome Developer: Migrating from a Packaged App to a Chrome App or Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/migrating)
- [Stack Overflow: Difference between a Packaged App and a Legacy Packaged App in Chrome](//stackoverflow.com/questions/14850788/difference-between-a-packaged-app-and-a-legacy-packaged-app-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a context menu item on your icon to open your options.

Add the "contextMenus" permission, then add something like this to your background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({ id: "options", title: "Options", contexts: ["launcher"] })
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info) {
  if(info.menuItemId == "options") {
    chrome.app.window.create("options.html")
  }
})
```

Comment: To highlight the main idea, for Apps you don't have specific UI to display options (as the Apps are supposed to be independent from the browser) - they should be displayed in your app, either in a separate window or somehow within your main one, and invoked from the app itself. Daniel's answer shows how to invoke it from the launcher.

Comment: Hmm `chrome.contextMenus` is undefined? Oh, missing app permission - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: Well, that kind of works, but I think there is a bug in Chrome. Whether or not it "works" depends on your expectation of what makes up the "launcher": the context menu is applied to the OS-native one (the Chrome App List icon in the Dock on my Mac) but it is **not** shown in the Chrome-builtin launcher `chrome://apps`. :-/