# Options page for Chrome packaged app for kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to write a "Chrome App" (not a Chrome extension, but an app that e.g. can run in kiosk mode) that basically is only opening a full screen browser that is displaying a web page.

This app needs some configuration informations, e.g. the URL for that web page should be settable by the admin.

I would have expected to solve that by specifying an options page. But it seems that's not possible, on purpose: cf. e.g. [How do I handle options in a packaged Chrome App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645683/how-do-i-handle-options-in-a-packaged-chrome-app).
The solution described there doesn't work for me for two reasons:

- The context menus / right click is already used by my web page (it's actually disabled on purpose to prevent mistakes)
- Only the admin should be able to change settings (think of a hotel environment)

How can I achive that goal?

I can't do anything fancy as the admin most likely isn't an IT expert. He will get an HowTo with simple steps to set up the device, that's it. All major config / setup information will come from a central server - but the URL to that server must be setup first...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a keyboard combo that, when pressed, displays a login gate over a menu to set the url and password. You may also want to display the locked menu automatically during setup, when the url is not yet set.

You'll need to permanently store the password and url using the [chrome.storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [ "storage" ]
```

You can handle the keyboard shortcut using the [chrome.commands api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands).

manifest.json:

```
"commands": {
 "adminmenu": {
  "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+A" },
  "description": "Show admin menu"
} }
```

main.js:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(showadmin)
```

You can handle the menu and password gate using the [dialog element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

main.html:

```
<dialog id="adminpassword">
 Admin options. Press alt a to reopen.
 <br><br>
 Admin password: <input type="text" id="enterpassword">
 <br><br>
 <button id="close">Close</button>
 <button id="unlock" style="float: right">Unlock</button>
</dialog>
<dialog id="adminoptions">
 Admin options. Press alt a to reopen.
 <br><br>
 New password: <input type="text" id="newpassword">
 <br><br>
 Site url: <input type="text" id="newurl">
 <br><br>
 <button id="close">Close</button>
 <button id="save" style="float: right">Save</button>
</dialog>
```

On correct password entered and unlock button clicked, open the admin options. Close the dialogs when the close button is clicked. Save the updated values when the save button is clicked.

main.js:

```
var passworddialog = document.querySelector("#adminpassword")
var admindialog = document.querySelector("#adminoptions")
var closepassword = passworddialog.querySelector("#close")
var closeadmin = admindialog.querySelector("#close")
var unlockadmin = passworddialog.querySelector("#unlock")
var saveoptions = admindialog.querySelector("#save")
var enterpassword = passworddialog.querySelector("#enterpassword")
var newpassword = admindialog.querySelector("#newpassword")
var newurl = admindialog.querySelector("#newurl")

function showadmin() {
 passworddialog.showModal()
}

closepassword.addEventListener("click", function() {
 passworddialog.close()
})
closeadmin.addEventListener("click", function() {
 admindialog.close()
})

unlockadmin.addEventListener("click", function() {
 chrome.storage.local.get("password", function(storage) {
  passworddialog.close()
  if(enterpassword.value == storage.password) {
   admindialog.showModal()
} }) })

saveoptions.addEventListener("click", function() {
 chrome.storage.local.set({ password: newpassword.value, url: newurl.value })
})
```

On load, set the default password if it is not defined and open the login menu. Otherwise, populate the admin options dialog.

main.js:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(storage) {
 if(storage.password) {
  newpassword.value = storage.password
 } else {
  chrome.storage.local.set({ password: "admin" })
 }
 if(storage.url) {
  newurl.value = storage.url
 } else {
  showadmin()
} })
```